# Drag and drop of QTreeWidgetItem does not work properly

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I subclassed a `QTreeWidget` in order to reimplement the `protected` functionalities of `drag` and `drop` in order to drag drop parents and children of a `QTreeWidget`.

It almost works and **the problem** is that as soon as I try to drag and drop either children or parents, they are erased as soon as I drop them.
Source code can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/ERaggi/qtreewidgetdragdrop/src/master/) in case you need to see what is going on.

Also if I try to drag-drop the parent, it unfortunately does not move and nothing happens.

See below the strange effect for the children:

I drag the child "Original" to drop it right under "Sample" and this procedure seems to work correctly:

[image: ddrop]

After dropping "Original" as you can see the index seems to be there but it seems to be partially erased:

[image: ddrop2]

I am not sure exactly of what is going on and why the children seems to not completely be dropped correctly and why the parents are literally not moving.

Below the code of the minimal verifiable example:

**mainwindow.h**

```
#include <QMainWindow>

class QTreeWidget;
class QTreeWidgetItem;


QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
    QTreeWidgetItem *createItem(const QString &name, const QString &iconPath);
    
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QTreeWidget *widget;
    QString m_Name;
    QString m_Path;

    };
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ui->treeWidget->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
    ui->treeWidget->setDragEnabled(true);
    ui->treeWidget->viewport()->setAcceptDrops(true);
    ui->treeWidget->setDropIndicatorShown(true);
    ui->treeWidget->setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::InternalMove);

    auto *top1 = createItem("Images", "/home/ui/qrc/laserscan.png");
    auto *top2 = createItem("Path", "/home/ui/qrc/laserscan.png");

    top1->addChild(createItem("Original", "/home/ui/qrc/laserscan.png"));
    top1->addChild(createItem("Sample", "/home/ui/qrc/laserscan.png"));

    top2->addChild(createItem("Left Side", "/home/ui/qrc/laserscan.png"));
    top2->addChild(createItem("Right Side", "/home/ui/qrc/laserscan.png"));

    ui->treeWidget->addTopLevelItems({ top1, top2 });

   // Below I am assigning to each parent/children a checkbox
    const int n_tops = ui->treeWidget->topLevelItemCount();
    for(int a = 0; a<n_tops; ++a) {
        const int n_children = ui->treeWidget->topLevelItem(a)->childCount();
        qtreewidgetitem_assign_qcheckbox(ui->treeWidget, ui->treeWidget->topLevelItem(a));
        for(int b = 0; b<n_children; ++b) {
            qtreewidgetitem_assign_qcheckbox(ui->treeWidget, ui->treeWidget->topLevelItem(a)->child(b));
        }
    }
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

QTreeWidgetItem *MainWindow::createItem(const QString &name, const QString &iconPath)
{
    auto *item = new QTreeWidgetItem(QStringList{name});
    item->setIcon(0, QIcon(iconPath));
    return item;
}
```

**maphelpers.h**

```
#include <QTreeWidget>
#include <QTreeWidgetItem>

void qtreewidgetitem_assign_qcheckbox(QTreeWidget *tree_widget, QTreeWidgetItem *tree_item);

#endif // MAPHELPERS_H
```

**maphelpers.cpp**

```
#include <QTreeWidget>

void qtreewidgetitem_assign_qcheckbox(QTreeWidget *tree_widget, QTreeWidgetItem *tree_item)
{
    MyCheckBoxMap *myCheckBoxMap = new MyCheckBoxMap(tree_item);
    tree_widget->setItemWidget(tree_item, MAP_COLUMN, myCheckBoxMap);
}
```

Below how I subclassed `QTreeWidget`:

**customtreewidget.h**

```
#include <QTreeWidget>

class CustomTreeWidget : public QTreeWidget
{
public:
    CustomTreeWidget(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
protected:
    void dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event) override;
    void dropEvent(QDropEvent *event) override;
private:
    QTreeWidgetItem *draggedItem;
};

#endif // CUSTOMTREEWIDGET_H
```

**customtreewidget.cpp**

```
CustomTreeWidget::CustomTreeWidget(QWidget *parent)
{
    QTreeWidgetItem* parentItem = new QTreeWidgetItem();
    parentItem->setText(0, "Test");
    parentItem->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsSelectable | Qt::ItemIsDropEnabled);

    int num_rows = topLevelItemCount();

    for(int i = 0; i < num_rows; ++i)
    {
      int nChildren = topLevelItem(i)->childCount();
      QTreeWidgetItem* pItem = new QTreeWidgetItem(parentItem);
      for(int j = 0; j < nChildren; ++j) {
          pItem->setText(0, QString("Number %1").arg(i) );
          pItem->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsSelectable | Qt::ItemIsDragEnabled);
          pItem->addChild(pItem);
          topLevelItem(i)->child(j);
      }
    }
}

void CustomTreeWidget::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event)
{
    draggedItem = currentItem();
    QTreeWidget::dragEnterEvent(event);
}

void CustomTreeWidget::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)
{
    QModelIndex droppedIndex = indexAt(event->pos());
    if(!droppedIndex.isValid()) {
        return;
    }

    if(draggedItem) {
        QTreeWidgetItem *mParent = draggedItem->parent();
        if(mParent) {
            if(itemFromIndex(droppedIndex.parent()) != mParent)
                return;
                mParent->removeChild(draggedItem);
                mParent->insertChild(droppedIndex.row(), draggedItem);
        }
    }
}
```

## What I have done so far and what I have tried:

**1)** According to official documentation it is possible to use [QTreeWidgetItemIterator Class](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtreewidgetitemiterator.html) and i tried to go that way and in fact you can see below my initial implementation idea, but this didn't really bring me anywhere:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    auto *top1 = createItem("Images", "/home/ui/qrc/laserscan.png");
    auto *top2 = createItem("Path", "/home/ui/qrc/laserscan.png");
    
    top1->addChild(createItem("Original", "/home/ui/qrc/laserscan.png"));
    top1->addChild(createItem("Sample", "/home/ui/qrc/laserscan.png"));
    
    top2->addChild(createItem("Left Side", "/home/ui/qrc/laserscan.png"));
    top2->addChild(createItem("Right Side", "/home/ui/qrc/laserscan.png"));
    
    ui->treeWidget->addTopLevelItems({ top1, top2 });

    const int n_tops = ui->treeWidget->topLevelItemCount();

    // Below I am assigning to each parent/children a checkbox
    for(int a = 0; a<n_tops; ++a) {
        const int n_children = ui->treeWidget->topLevelItem(a)->childCount();
        qtreewidgetitem_assign_qcheckbox(ui->treeWidget, ui->treeWidget->topLevelItem(a));
        for(int b = 0; b<n_children; ++b) {
            qtreewidgetitem_assign_qcheckbox(ui->treeWidget, ui->treeWidget->topLevelItem(a)->child(b));
        }
    }

    QTreeWidgetItem *parentItem = Q_NULLPTR;
    QTreeWidgetItem *childItem = Q_NULLPTR;

    QTreeWidgetItemIterator it(ui->treeWidget);
       while (*it) {
           parentItem = new QTreeWidgetItem(ui->treeWidget);
           //parentItem->setText(0, it.key());
           foreach (const auto &str, it) {
               childItem = new QTreeWidgetItem;
               childItem->setText(0, str);
               parentItem->addChild(childItem);
           }
       }
}
```

**2)** After further research in the official documentation I decided to approach the problem applying the [QMapIterator Class](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmapiterator.html) I wanted to keep the constructor as I structured initially and figured that passing through a `QMap` meant to rewrite the constructor in a different way, basically the implementation idea below, but didn't want to pass that way:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    auto *top1 = createItem("Images", "/home/ui/qrc/laserscan.png");
    auto *top2 = createItem("Path", "/home/ui/qrc/laserscan.png");
    
    top1->addChild(createItem("Original", "/home/ui/qrc/laserscan.png"));
    top1->addChild(createItem("Sample", "/home/ui/qrc/laserscan.png"));
    
    top2->addChild(createItem("Left Side", "/home/ui/qrc/laserscan.png"));
    top2->addChild(createItem("Right Side", "/home/ui/qrc/laserscan.png"));
    
    ui->treeWidget->addTopLevelItems({ top1, top2 });
    ui->treeWidget->addTopLevelItems({ top1, top2 });

    const int n_tops = ui->treeWidget->topLevelItemCount();

    // Below I am assigning to each parent/children a checkbox
    for(int a = 0; a<n_tops; ++a) {
        const int n_children = ui->treeWidget->topLevelItem(a)->childCount();
        qtreewidgetitem_assign_qcheckbox(ui->treeWidget, ui->treeWidget->topLevelItem(a));
        for(int b = 0; b<n_children; ++b) {
            qtreewidgetitem_assign_qcheckbox(ui->treeWidget, ui->treeWidget->topLevelItem(a)->child(b));
        }
    }

    QTreeWidgetItem *parentItem = Q_NULLPTR;
    QTreeWidgetItem *childItem = Q_NULLPTR;

    QMapIterator<QString, QStringList> i(treeMap);
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        i.next();
        parentItem = new QTreeWidgetItem(widget);
        parentItem->setText(0, i.key());
        foreach (const auto &str, i.value()) {
            childItem = new QTreeWidgetItem;
            childItem->setText(0, str);
            parentItem->addChild(childItem);
        }
    }
}
```

**3)** After more research I cam across [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31434725/iteration-of-a-qtreewidget), and [this other source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21283934/qtreewidget-reordering-child-items-by-dragging) which was useful (in particular the last post) as guidance to the implementation of the subclassing of the `QTreeWidget`.

Now I am stuck as I am trying to figure out why, despite all the things I tried, I achieved a 90% working application and, therefore, what is missing about it?

Thanks for providing guidance on how to solve this problem.

Comment: If you just need drag and drop, why do you have to subclass?

Comment: It seems to me that the assign checkbox section of your code is the culprit. If you comment out that part, the items can be dragged and dropped normally. Maybe the checkboxes are handling the mouse events.

Comment: @NgocMinhNguyen, thanks for stopping by and read the question. Indeed!! The culprit are the checkboxes!! If I comment that for loop everything works fine...but I don't understand why...I added that class too in the question. Do you see anything specific that triggers that behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the checkboxes are handling the mouse events and don't let the events go through to the item. To have the desired behavior, you should remove this part:

```
const int n_tops = ui->treeWidget->topLevelItemCount();

for(int a = 0; a<n_tops; ++a) {
    const int n_children = ui->treeWidget->topLevelItem(a)->childCount();
    qtreewidgetitem_assign_qcheckbox(ui->treeWidget, ui->treeWidget->topLevelItem(a));
    for(int b = 0; b<n_children; ++b) {
        qtreewidgetitem_assign_qcheckbox(ui->treeWidget, ui->treeWidget->topLevelItem(a)->child(b));
    }
}
```

And in the `createItem()` function:

```
QTreeWidgetItem *MainWindow::createItem(const QString &name, const QString &iconPath)
{
    auto *item = new QTreeWidgetItem(QStringList{name});
    item->setCheckState(0, Qt::Unchecked);
    item->setIcon(0, QIcon(iconPath));
    item->setFlags(item->flags() | Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable);
    return item;
}
```

Comment: I see! Yes now it works very well exactly as I was looking for! Thank you very much for your edits and for your time n reading and answering my question! :) :)